# Why capturing images of bright lights such as LED screens become pink?

Tags: android, android-camera

In my camera app, whenever i am capturing images of bright lights such as LED screens. The white images become pink. WHY ?

i am getting bright images like [this](http://s14.directupload.net/images/140227/ktydwny9.jpg) one

Here is what i have used to capture images:

```
  btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        if (safeToTakePicture) {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture); 
            safeToTakePicture = false;
            }
         }
    });

   @Override
    public void onResume() {  
        super.onResume();   
        camera=Camera.open(); 
    }  

    @Override   
    public void onPause() {  
        super.onPause();  
        if (inPreview) {  
            camera.stopPreview();   
        }   
        camera.release();   
        camera=null;   
        inPreview=false;         
     }   


    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
            Camera.Parameters parameters) {
            Camera.Size result=null;

                for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
                    if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
                        if (result == null) {
                            result=size;
                        }
                        else {
                            int resultArea=result.width * result.height;
                            int newArea=size.width * size.height;

                            if (newArea > resultArea) {
                                result=size;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return(result);
            }

        private Camera.Size getSmallestPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
            Camera.Size result=null;

            for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
                if (result == null) {
                    result=size;
                }
                else {
                    int resultArea=result.width * result.height;
                    int newArea=size.width * size.height;

                    if (newArea < resultArea) {
                        result=size;
                    }
                }
            }

            return(result);
        }

     SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {     
            try {        
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder); 
                }   catch (Throwable t) {   
                    Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
                            "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
                    Toast.makeText(CameraLauncherActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
                    }     
                }      

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format, int width,int height) {
            params = camera.getParameters();       
            Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, params);  
            Camera.Size pictureSize=getSmallestPictureSize(params);
            if (size != null && pictureSize != null) {      
                params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                params.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width,
                        pictureSize.height);
                camera.setParameters(params);       
                camera.startPreview();  
                safeToTakePicture = true;
                inPreview=true;                      
            }      

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            }   
        };       
    }
```

I did not find any solution, and here i am looking for the best way to get bright screen images in white itself not in pink.

Comment: On multiple devices or one specific device?  If the latter, which device?  Do you see the same thing when using the Camera app?